# SSL Cert.for IIS Virtual Directory vs Website

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

Our infrastructure guys have told me that it's not possible to assign SSL Cert. for Virtual Directories.  But only possible for IIS Websites.

Could anyone please help me to confirm the above? And if it's possible, is the import cert. similar to Web Site.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, SSL certificate can be assigned only on `Website` level. When encrypted request come to  the server it's not possible to determine its URL until the request is decrypted. To find correct certificate for description, request IP address is used, and IP address is configured on `Website` level only to which in turn is assigned SSL Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I am interested to find out too. I know apache does not support ssl cert on virtual directories.